# Selenium WD | How to deliver a List <WebElement> & links that are inside the list, to another class?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have class #1, that has a List , that looks up for links on page, and remembers them. How, syntax-wise, Do I deliver the list from class #1 to class #2 while having a boolean method?

**Meaning how would look the method in class #2, that would get this list?**
note : I would like to use a loop in class #2 and click on each link I have inside this list

> class #1

```
public class NavigateToInstrumentsInMarkets {

    public static boolean EnterInstrumentViaMarkets (WebDriver driver,boolean statusOfTest) throws InterruptedException
    {


        statusOfTest = false;

        int size = 2;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) {

            // Create a list of instruments
            List <WebElement> list2 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[nowrap='nowrap']>a"));
            String name = list2.get(i).getText(); // instrument's name taken from list

            try {

                size = list2.size();
                Thread.sleep(3000);



                // print instruments name as exception
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                statusOfTest = true;

            }

            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {

                System.out.println("Page of instrument not found, Page not found error 404, Instruments name that failed to load is " +name );
                statusOfTest = false;
            }

            // Print insturment's name

            try {
                WebElement instrumentName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='float_lang_base_1 relativeAttr']"));
                System.out.println(instrumentName.getText());
            }



            catch (NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot find instrument's name in inner page, instrument's name is" +name );
                statusOfTest = false;
            }


            // Check if Stock is opened/closed
            WebElement Status = null;
            InstrumentRedOrGreenClock.runTestClock (driver,  Status);


        }
        return statusOfTest;
    }
```

Comment: What you want ? to call this class #1 method to another class ?

Comment: Hi, I have re-edited the question so it would be clearer hopefully

Answer (score 1):

[Best practice](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/08/24/writing-great-unit-tests-best-and-worst-practises/) is to have each test be independent of each other so in this case, you shouldn't pass the list from one test to another. Your list seems pretty simple to fetch, just repeat the fetch in test2 and keep them separated.

I would also suggest that you take advantage of a test framework like TestNG or JUnit instead of writing your own test logic. It will not only help with asserts (validations) but also in constructing and running tests.

Answer (score 0):

If I needed to share list of elements between classes, I would create separate page object,  class #3, which would be responsible for delivering list. if I understand correctly, this is the list you want:

```
List <WebElement> list2 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[nowrap='nowrap']>a"));
```

class 3 would look something like:

```
public class InstrumentsSection {
    private IWebDriver driver;
    public InstrumentsSection(IWebDriver driver) 
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public List<WebElement> getInstruments()
    {
        return driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[nowrap='nowrap']>a"));
    }
}
```

I would instantiate class and get list in both class 1 and class 2.